# Bizunit How do I set up WebServiceStep.RequestBody()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, biztalk

I'm currently trying to test BizTalk with `BizUnit` but the documentation is dreadful. At the minute while waiting for a stable service I am looking at the `WebServiceStep` class.

I was wondering if anyone has an example on how to set up the SOAP body. I am trying to create the test in code (not XAML) so need to use the `WebServiceStep.RequestBody`.

I've thought about maybe having a class that inherits of `DataLoaderBase` but I am unsure on how to set up this correctly. Any help would be grateful.

So far I have the following code:

```
  public static void ExecuteSoap(string url, string title, string space)
  {
        var test = new TestCase();
        var step = new WebServiceStep();

        step.ServiceUrl = url;
        step.FailOnError = true;

        step.SoapHeaders = new Collection<SoapHeader>();
        step.SoapHeaders.Add(new SoapHeader() 
        {
            HeaderName = title, 
            HeaderNameSpace = space 
        });

        // Error here because of DataLoaderBase being abstract
        // step.RequestBody = new DataLoaderBase(); 

        test.ExecutionSteps.Add(step);

        Execute(test);
 }
```

Also it's not important but if anyone has a better alternative to BizUnit I would be interested to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FileDataLoader fileLoader = new FileDataLoader() { FilePath = "c:\Input\Employee.xml" };
step.RequestBody = fileLoader;
```

Depending upon your source of input XML, you can specify FileDataLoader, XmlDataLoader

Comment: Ive decided to move on from using BizUnit but thank you for your response.